# How can GCC -ftree-partial-pre generate more assembly but run faster?

Tags: assembly, g++, x86-64, code-generation, compiler-optimization

When implementing different sort algorithms for my computer science class I stumbled upon a curious optimization case with GCC(version 12.2).

I tried programming selection sort with two different variants: once storing the value of the current minimum (selection_sort) and once with only storing the index of the current minimum value (selection_nostore_sort)

links to godbolt and quick-bench (code & relevant assembly is also down below): 
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Gdab1xenf 
https://quick-bench.com/q/5xh06k8DD9qi1RCFvFMVBdbkDuw

I was expecting the *nostore* version to be slower because it has to reach out into the array for comparisons.
This was the case up to `-O2`, however with `-O3` *nostore* runs about 10% faster (both on my local machine i7-10750H and quick-bench)
Testing out all the extra optimizations that `-O3`enables I was able to figure out that `-O2 -ftree-partial-pre` produces the same result.

When checking out the generated assembly in both cases I noticed that `-ftree-partial-pre` actually produces more assembler code yet runs faster.

I dont see any obvious reason why the `-ftree-partial-pre` version runs faster, what could be the causes here?
Thanks a lot for your help! My professors were sadly unable to give me an explanation.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
using std::size_t;

const size_t DATA_ELEMS = 10'000;
const size_t RAND_RANGE = 1'000'000;

std::vector<size_t> random_data() 
{
    std::srand(42);
    std::vector<size_t> result(DATA_ELEMS);
    const auto rand_size_t_range = [] () -> size_t {
        return std::rand() % RAND_RANGE;
    };
    std::generate(result.begin(), result.end(), rand_size_t_range);

    return result;
}

inline void swap(std::vector<size_t> &a, size_t i1, size_t i2)
{
    size_t h = a[i1];
    a[i1] = a[i2];
    a[i2] = h;
}

void selection_sort(std::vector<size_t> &a)
{

    for (size_t k = 0; k < a.size(); k++)
    {
        size_t min = a[k];
        size_t i_min = k;
        for (size_t i = k + 1; i < a.size(); i++)
        {
            if (a[i] < min)
            {
                min = a[i];
                i_min = i;
            }
        }
        if (i_min != k)
        {
            swap(a, i_min, k);
        }
    }
}

/*
    This is normally quite a bit slower than selection_sort
    However compiling with -02 -ftree-partial-pre seems to make this function
    quite a bit faster than selection_sort
*/
void selection_nostore_sort(std::vector<size_t> &a)
{
    for (size_t k = 0; k < a.size(); k++)
    {
        size_t i_min = k;
        for (size_t i = k + 1; i < a.size(); i++)
        {
            if (a[i] < a[i_min])
            {
                i_min = i;
            }
        }
        if (i_min != k)
        {
            swap(a, i_min, k);
        }
    }
}
```

The `-O2` version

```
selection_nostore_sort(std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >&):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rsi, rax
        sub     rsi, rcx
        sar     rsi, 3
        cmp     rcx, rax
        je      .L10
        xor     r8d, r8d
        lea     rdi, [r8+1]
        cmp     rdi, rsi
        jnb     .L10
.L18:
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     rdx, r8
.L13:
        mov     r9, QWORD PTR [rcx+rdx*8]
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rcx+rax*8], r9
        cmovb   rdx, rax
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     rsi, rax
        jne     .L13
        cmp     rdx, r8
        je      .L14
        lea     rax, [rcx+rdx*8]
        mov     r8, QWORD PTR [rcx-8+rdi*8]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], r8
        mov     QWORD PTR [rcx-8+rdi*8], rdx
.L14:
        mov     r8, rdi
        lea     rdi, [r8+1]
        cmp     rdi, rsi
        jb      .L18
.L10:
        ret
```

The `-O3` / `-O2 -ftree-partial-pre` version

```
selection_nostore_sort(std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >&):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     r10, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     r9, rax
        sub     r9, r10
        sar     r9, 3
        cmp     r10, rax
        je      .L21
        push    r12
        lea     r11, [r10+8]
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        xor     ebx, ebx
        lea     rbp, [rbx+1]
        cmp     rbp, r9
        jnb     .L10
.L26:
        mov     r12, QWORD PTR [r11-8]
        mov     rax, r11
        mov     rdx, rbp
        mov     r8, rbx
        mov     rsi, r12
        jmp     .L14
.L25:
        add     rdx, 1
        lea     rdi, [r10+r8*8]
        add     rax, 8
        cmp     rdx, r9
        je      .L24
.L14:
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rdi, rax
        cmp     rcx, rsi
        jnb     .L25
        mov     r8, rdx
        add     rdx, 1
        mov     rsi, rcx
        add     rax, 8
        cmp     rdx, r9
        jne     .L14
.L24:
        cmp     r8, rbx
        je      .L15
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], r12
        mov     QWORD PTR [r11-8], rsi
.L15:
        mov     rbx, rbp
        add     r11, 8
        lea     rbp, [rbx+1]
        cmp     rbp, r9
        jb      .L26
.L10:
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
.L21:
        ret
```

Comment: code size isn't a good indicator of performance. There are two factors, 1. how many times each instruction is executed, e.g. a loop implemented using 10 instructions running twice might be slower than an unrolled loop implemented using 18 instructions running once. 2. some instructions or sequences of instructions are faster than others

Comment: Note that the -O3 version **does** store the minimum value in `rsi` but that of course should not make it faster than your explicit version.

Comment: Measuring performance on modern hardware is nebulous at best, considering all the things that can affect it. Caching, pipelines, branch prediction, environment variables... Back in the day all you had to do was count clock cycles.

Comment: @Jester thanks! I didnt see that at first its incredible how GCC is able to reason about code

Comment: @puppydrum64 good point I will try to replicate the results on a different architecture and post the results

Comment: @AlanBirtles do you see any such case in my assembly? I am generally aware of these diffrences but a novice at assembly at best. Could it maybe also be an alignment issue? (referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470873/why-does-gcc-generate-15-20-faster-code-if-i-optimize-for-size-instead-of-speed?rq=1)

Comment: No, I'm not an assembly expert either, in very much in the "let the optimiser do it's job and worry about it later if it's too slow" camp

Comment: The things to look for are latency bottlenecks and maybe front-end uop throughput limits. ([What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607391))  And in branchy code, perhaps something that has the inputs ready sooner for the branch to execute and check the branch-prediction, reducing mispredict cost.

Comment: And possibly just code-alignment quirks, especially since you're on a Skylake-derived microarchitecture (Comet Lake).  First thing to try is **[How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646)** and see if that makes them both equal speed.  Unfortunately QuickBench's inability to supply more options makes it unusable for micro-benchmarking in cases where this might be a factor, especially since you don't know what CPU it ran on.  (Sky/Cascade Lake, Ice Lake, or maybe Zen 3.)