What does memory aligning a function to 32 do?
In HTSlib, Bonfield memory aligns a series of methods to 32. Why does it do this and what does it achieve?
So, for example here there's this code:
    if (type == 'c') {
        if (!(q = sam_parse_Bc_vals(b, q, &nused, &nalloc, &overflow)))
            return -1;
    } else if (type == 'C') {
        if (!(q = sam_parse_BC_vals(b, q, &nused, &nalloc, &overflow)))
            return -1;
    } else if (type == 's') {
        if (!(q = sam_parse_Bs_vals(b, q, &nused, &nalloc, &overflow)))
            return -1;
    } else if (type == 'S') {
    //... etc.
    }

And if you look at the function definitions, you see this:
HTS_ALIGN32
static char *sam_parse_Bc_vals(bam1_t *b, char *q, uint32_t *nused,
                               uint32_t *nalloc, int *overflow) {
    while (*q == ',') {
        if ((*nused)++ >= (*nalloc)) {
            if (grow_B_array(b, nalloc, 1) < 0)
                return NULL;
        }
        *(b->data + b->l_data) = hts_str2int(q + 1, &q, 8, overflow);
        b->l_data++;
    }
    return q;
}

That HTS_ALIGN32 is a macro for #define HTS_ALIGN32 __attribute__((aligned(32)))
What performance limitation does this overcome? (Or is there another reason that it is doing this?)

Maybe it's related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570226/376390

Aligning to cache line size makes sense to reduce memory operations

Given that the function returns the value passed in as argument q, I don't see how it can ensure that the return value is 32-byte aligned.  It depends a bit on what the hts_str2int() function does — it could fix the alignment if *q points to a comma, but it isn't executed if q does not point to a comma.  It's tempting to say that it is pointless and/or inaccurate.

@JonathanLeffler your comment assumes that the alignment applies to the address that is returned by the function. Isn't it the function address that is aligned to 32 bytes?

@Gerhardh — you may well be right.

Looking a the pull request, this was made for performance reasons.
It seems that alignment to 32bits speeds up the processing, or at least eliminates fuzziness in the results.
I would have actually never expected that a compiler would not align functions to 32bits in a 32bit microcontroller architecture. It would result in performance impact while fetching. Maybe some optimisation settings like -Os would do this to squeeze out the most of the available space.
